# Print matching lines without using a hash

Tags: perl

i want to match two different file for similar line in both the files without using hash function. but i am getting no clue of doing that. can you please help

here is my input:

#### file1:

```
delhi  
bombay  
kolkata  
shimla  
ghuhati
```

#### File2:

```
london  
delhi  
jammu  
punjab  
shimla
```

#### output:

```
delhi  
shimla
```

#### Stub of code:

```
#/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @line1 = <file1>;
my @line2 = <file2>;

while (<file1>) {
    do stuff;
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with using hash?

Comment: because it uses a lot of memory for long data files as told by teacher ..

Comment: @user3483833: Your teacher needs to explain when and why a hash is the wrong solution. It is usually best to try the obvious solution, and make changes only if there is a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need a very good reason not to use a hash to solve this problem. Is it a homework assignment?

This will do what you ask. It reads all of `file1` into an array, then reads through `file2` one line at a time, using `grep` to check whether the name appears in the array.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my @file1 = do {
  open my $fh, '<', 'file1.txt';
  <$fh>;
};
chomp @file1;

open my $fh, '<', 'file2.txt';
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
  chomp $line;
  print "$line\n" if grep { $_ eq $line } @file1;
}
```

**output**

```
delhi
shimla
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do it without using hash, in a very inefficient way:

```
my @line1 = <file1>;
my @line2 = <file2>;

foreach (@line1) {
    if (isElement($_, \@line2)) {
        print;
    }
}

sub isElement {
    my ($ele, $arr) = @_;

    foreach (@$arr) {
        if ($ele eq $_) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use hashes? Can I use modules?

The easiest way may be to avoid using Perl, but use the Unix `sort` and `comm` utilities:

```
$ sort -u file1.txt > file1.sort.txt
$ sort -u file2.txt > file2.sort.txt
# comm -12 file1.sort.txt file2.sort.txt
```

The `comm` utility prints out three columns: The first column are lines found only in the first file. The second column are lines found only in the second file, and the last column are lines found in both files. The `-12` parameter suppresses the printing of columns #1 and #2 giving you only the lines in common.

You could use a double loop where you compare each value with each other one as [Lee Duhem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23324711/368630) did, but that's pretty inefficient. The time it takes increases by the square of the number of items.